# Write string to file in the resources folder

Tags: java, file, resources

I am little bit confused as this is simple task but don't now why it's not working.

I need to write a string to file  in the `resources` folder. But my code doesn't work.

```
 String json = "string with json";
 URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.json");
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(resource.toURI()));
 fw.write(json);
```

But after this `file.json` is still empty. Thanks for any help.

Comment: try `fw.close()` or `fw.flush()`

Comment: @user16320675  thank you, looks like the problem was with IDE.  I have build project without IDE  and  everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this with most IDEs. The source folders are different than the target folders that are used at runtime.

Using Eclipse, when examining the contents of `resource.toURI()`, you should get a value of something like `target\test-classes\file.json`.

That is the location of the resource at runtime. You can write to that location, but it will not change the contents of your original source file. Using Eclipse, the location of the original source is `src\test\java\file.json`

The location of the original source is, most likely, unknown at runtime.